# Cannot globally export firebase

Tags: firebase, aurelia

When using aurelia-cli, in a newly made project, I'm trying to include firebase in my bundle using the following code:

```
  {
    "name": "firebase",
    "path": "../node_modules/firebase",
    "main":"firebase",
    "exports": "firebase"
  }
```

Based on their documentation, this should make firebase globally available in my app (similar to `$`for jQuery).

What's causing this not to work?

Comment: Did you include it under dependencies and used `import firebase from 'firebase'` wherever you want use firebase?

Comment: Hi @RobinsonCollado, that approach works, but is there any way to globally have my firebase available?

Answer (score 2):

In your main.js, try the following:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export function configure(aurelia) {

  ...

  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'your_api_key',
    authDomain: 'your_auth_domain',
    databaseURL: 'your_database_url',
    storageBucket: 'your_storage_bucket'
  });

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

In app.js:

```
// Import firebase if the project was created using the Aurelia-CLI
// If you're using the Aurelia Esnext-Skeleton, you don't have to import firebase
import firebase from 'firebase';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.some_ref = firebase.database().ref('some_path');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does NOT work. I've done exactly like you said, in main.js, imported firebase and then initialized it. Afterwards in app.js constructor I did a console.log(firebase); and I got an error that firebase is undefined!

Comment: You're correct! I updated my answer. Firebase isn't globalized like how you want it but it should get you up and running with Firebase. If you find out how to use Firebase globally (in a project created using the aurelia-cli),  I would love to know.